# import de TextStyle de java.time no funciona

Tags: java

Quiero extraer el mes de una fecha completa `(DD/MM/YYYY)`. He encontrado una forma de hacerlo:

```
int mes = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
String nombreMes = mes.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, new Locale("es", 
"ES"));
```

Pero me da problemas con el **TextStyle** de **java.time**: no me coge el `import`.

¿Habría que añadir alguna dependencia en el *pom.xml* para poder trabajar con los elementos de **java.time**? De ser así, ¿me pueden facilitar la dependencia para añadirla en el *pom.xml*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según puedo observar, tu primer error debería ser el nombre de la variable `mes`, porque la variable `int mes` no debe de tener el método `getDisplayName` que pertenecería a la variable `Calendar cal`; otro error es que `TextStyle.FULL` no es la clase que debes de utilizar: se debe utilizar `Calendar.LONG`. `TestStyle` funciona pero para la la clase `java.time.Month;`, en dado caso para tu ejemplo no es necesaria ya que implicaría pasos extras al convertir el mes a `Month` y después obtener el nombre.

Te dejo un ejemplo con las 2 formas de obtener el nombre del mes utilizando Calendar y Month:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Locale;

public class NombreMesUsandoCalendar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        // Obtenemos el nombre del mes utilizando el método `getDisplayName` correctamente.
        String nombreMes = cal.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, new Locale("es", "ES"));
        System.out.println(nombreMes);
    }
}

Texto de ejecución en consola:
julio
```

```
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Locale;

public class NombreMesUsandoMonth {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        // Obtenemos el numero del mes
        int numeroMes = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        // Pasamos el numero del mes a la Clase Month
        Month mes = Month.of(numeroMes + 1);
        // Obtenemos el nombre del mes de la variable mes de tipo Month
        String nombreMes = mes.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, new Locale("es", "ES"));

        System.out.println(nombreMes);
    }
}

Texto de ejecución en consola:
julio
```

Algo a tener en cuenta es que la clase `Calendar` pertenece al paquete `java.util` y tiene muchos errores de diseño: por ejemplo el número del mes en `Calendar` se inicia en cero (0=Enero, 1=Febrero ... 11=Diciembre) lo cual no es intuitivo.

La clase `Month` es del paquete `java.time` fue introducida en el Java 8, corrigiendo los problemas de `Calendar` y `java.util.Date`, por eso se debe sumar 1 para obtener el mes correcto `Month.of(numeroMes + 1);` porque enero es 1 en `java.time`. Lo mejor es que dejes de utilizar `Calendar` si es posible y que utilices las clases de `java.time` únicamente, serían `Instant, LocalDate y LocalDateTime` para el manejo de fecha y hora.

Comment: De acuerdo, muchas gracias por la explicación. Me ha quedado bastante mas claro.